# How do i time activity in forms in a rails 4 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, analytics

I am building an app where I want to time the actual activity in forms - entering text in text fields, clicking radio buttons and checkboxes, etc. - I would like to show users how long they spent actually entering data in their forms. This does not include time from opening the form to submitting it, since the user may not be actively typing, and may even have stepped away.

Is there any gem or library or functionality in rails or javascript that captures such data?

I looked at the benchmarking test features in rails, but that is mostly about automated benchmarking.

Comment: so let me get it clear you want the time taken to fill a form ie it should record the time taken to fill each form right

Comment: This is possible with JavaScript, but you need to more strictly define "entering data". How long can the user be inactive before the timing stops?

Comment: Yes, SRDP. Drenmi, I want a ballpark in minutes, not an exact time to the second - so, user can be inactive for, say, 15 seconds before pausing the timer and deducting those fifteen seconds. Timer resumes when user resumes typing. And timer ends when form is submitted.